# Как работают yandex/google карты?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, php

Здравствуйте! Интересует теория по данному вопросу, м.б. кто-то уже делал что-то подобное?
Интересует, как сделать на html/javascript/php такую карту, как например, в упомянутых сервисах, ну, естественно, несколько проще.
Так понимаю, изображение самой карты находится в background-е упорядоченных div-ов, которые можно таскать по экрану, а дивы, выходящие из за границ экрана подгружают изображения соответствующего масштаба в процессе появления? Так-же? А объекты нанесённые на карту, как точки-линии откуда появляются, и как на ней "закрепляются"? На досуге занимаюсь, ищу, смотрю, ковыряю, пытаюсь разобраться как это работает, и как реализовать, но что-то ничего толкового не гуглится.. М.б. правда кто сталкивался? Благодарю за внимание.

**UPD:**
В идеале подойдёт что-то вроде этого: http://www.sky-map.org/ куча дивов с автоподгрузкой, drug-n-drope, выпадающее окошко с информацией, при наведении курсора, вызов функции по клику на объект.

Answer (score 4):

Советую посмотреть как устроен [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/). У него открыты [исходиники](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Getting_The_Source) и есть [описание архитектуры](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop) для разработчиков.

Если вы не против готового решения, то можете воспользоваться YandexMapsAPI. Яндекс предоставляет [инструменты](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/map-custom.xml) для создания пользовательских карт.

Comment: Хорошая идея, но API работающих проектов не подойдёт, т.к. на моих картах, если я их когда-нибудь и сделаю, будут изображены вымышленные и рандомно сгенерированные местности) А с oupenStreet сейчас ознакомимся..

Comment: Вы похоже не поняли. Яндекс Карты позволяют создавать карты с пользовательскими картинками. Просто сервер должен отдавать по url вида mydomain.com/tiles/x={x}&y={y}&z={z} соответствующий кусочек карты. {x},{y} - координаты, {z} - уровень зума.

Comment: Не знал. Но тоже не совсем то, идея несколько в ином - сделать такой движок самому. Ну, только мега-облегчённый. Разбираюсь на данный момент с OSM..